# Any way to recover Google Apps Scripts project?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to delete a script of mine. After I had pressed delete I realized I deleted the entire project. All of my code... gone. Hours upon hour of work. Is there any possible way to recover it?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to locate it in the Trash and select Restore?  You did not mention 'Delete Forever' so I suspect your project is in the Trash (fingers crossed that it is still there)